# How to mix PHP with a string inside CodeIgniter function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, concatenation

I would like to dynamically set the `id` for each iteration of this radio button within a loop.

However have not been able to figure out the correct way of escaping strings and variables in the `id` portion. The quotes in that portion are failing to parse.

```
<?php 
echo form_radio($data['filename'], 0, '', 'class="uniform" id="'$data['ids']'"); 
?>
```

This uses the `form` helpers from CodeIgniter which [have this layout](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_radio).

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start with double quotes to get expanded variables, then escape nested ones with backslash

```
<?php 
echo form_radio($data['filename'], 0, '', "class=\"uniform\" id=\"$data[ids]\"");
```

Or use single quotes inside double

```
<?php 
echo form_radio($data['filename'], 0, '', "class='uniform' id='$data[ids]'");
```

Notice you don't need to quote single dimensional array indexes inside the square braces if inside double quotes

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = array(
        'filename' => 'test file_nm',
        'ids' => 'chb_ID'
    );

echo form_radio($data['filename'], 0, '', 'class="uniform" id="'.$data['ids'].'"');
```

It will output as following

```
<input type="radio" name="test file_nm" value="0"  class="uniform" id="chb_ID" />
```